# Why does NumberFormatInfo act differently in Azure environment?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have created some specific format extensions to use in Razor content rendering:

```
public static class FormatExtension
{
    private static CultureInfo BelgiumCulture { get; } = new CultureInfo("nl-BE");
    private static NumberFormatInfo DecimalFormatInfo => BelgiumCulture.NumberFormat;

    public static string FormatAmountN2(this decimal value)
    {
        FormattableString template = $"{value:N2}";
        return template.ToString(DecimalFormatInfo);
    }
}
```

When this code is executed:

```
Debug.WriteLine(12345m.FormatAmountN2());
```

The output in my dev environment is:

```
12.345,00
```

The output on Azure app service is:

```
12 345,00
```

So, space " " instead of dot "." is used as a group separator and that is wrong.

Why am I experiencing this?

Project is Asp.net Core 3.0 with Razor

Edit:

I have made a bit of research and I can confirm that problem is related to Azure:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var format = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-BE", false).NumberFormat;
        Console.WriteLine($"Decimal separator: {format.NumberDecimalSeparator}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Group separator: {format.NumberGroupSeparator}");
    }
}
```

When I run this sample in .Net Fiddle, I get correct result - comma and dot.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SONgb3

When I run this sample in https://try.dot.net,
which is executed as an Azure function (stumbled on that info somewhere),
result is wrong - comma and space.

Comment: @Stefan well, if I use this specific culture number format info from `nl-BE` should not that give me same result on every machine or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you by any chance use an azure app service running on linux and are developing on a windows machine, or vice versa?

Comment: @Compufreak, Dev is on Windows machine, For the App service - I don't know, how can I see that?

Comment: Usually you would know as you have to actively opt in for this AFAIK ;)
You can see it at the App Service Plan. If you open it in the Azure Portal and below the heading it says "App Service Plan" it is windows.  If it says "Linux App", it's a linux plan. There's also a small pinguin next to the service plan icon.

Comment: @Compufreak, thanks for the support, it appears to be a windows plan.

Comment: Hm that's interesting. My best guess still would be some difference in the installed locales or runtimes,  but maybe someone else can come up with a better explanation. Good luck ;)

Comment: Yea, you are right. I verified this behavior by debugging in local versus running in a Azure function app. Let me raise a bug internally and update you on this. Meanwhile, pls check my below response as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. I verified this behavior by debugging in local versus running in a hosted Azure function app. As a workaround, you can use below code:

```
var format = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-BE", false).NumberFormat;
    format.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

    var value = 1234567;
        FormattableString template = $"{value:N2}";
    var ans = template.ToString(format);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Number seperated: {ans}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Decimal separator: '{format.NumberDecimalSeparator}'");
        Console.WriteLine($"Group separator: '{format.NumberGroupSeparator}'");
```